# How to upload/set dynamic(using axios) data in drilldown map on click event?

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts

So, I have a drill down map, where I set value in the map using axios. Initially, I set data state wise, then upon click event of that state, I again have to call axios request to get district wise data.

I found the click event but not able to reflect the changes as I desire.

Following is my code link:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/61l014j2mz

P.S

Code wont compile due to dependencies.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. The code in that link is not runnable.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: you need to build the child chart data first and pass this to the  linked data object before rendering the chart

Answer (score 0):

You can implement FusionCharts supported link attribute for navigating a specific URL while clicking over a map plot. Please check the following way.

You can try this case with below code, hope it would help you -

```
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import ReactFusioncharts from "react-fusioncharts";

// Resolves charts dependancy
charts(FusionCharts);

const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Average Annual Population Growth",
    subcaption: "Click on a continent to see trend from 1955-2015",
    numbersuffix: "%",
    includevalueinlabels: "1",
    labelsepchar: ": ",
    entityfillhovercolor: "#FFF9C4",
    theme: "candy"
  },
  colorrange: {
    minvalue: "0",
    code: "#FFE0B2",
    gradient: "1",
    color: [
      {
        minvalue: "0.5",
        maxvalue: "1.0",
        color: "#FFD74D"
      },
      {
        minvalue: "1.0",
        maxvalue: "2.0",
        color: "#FB8C00"
      },
      {
        minvalue: "2.0",
        maxvalue: "3.0",
        color: "#E65100"
      }
    ]
  },
  data: [
    {
      id: "NA",
      value: ".82",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-NAM"
    },
    {
      id: "SA",
      value: "2.04",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-SAM"
    },
    {
      id: "AS",
      value: "1.78",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-ASI"
    },
    {
      id: "EU",
      value: ".40",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-EUP"
    },
    {
      id: "AF",
      value: "2.58",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-AFC"
    },
    {
      id: "AU",
      value: "1.30",
      showlabel: "1",
      link: "newchart-json-AUS"
    }
  ],
  linkeddata: [
    {
      id: "NAM",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - North America",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          palettecolors: "FFD74D",
          theme: "candy"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "1.5078"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "1.5502"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "1.3121"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "0.8648"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "0.6402"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "0.62"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "0.6748"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "0.6882"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "0.6804"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "0.5627"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "0.5373"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "0.5536"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "0.4291"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "SAM",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - South America",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          palettecolors: "E65100",
          theme: "candy"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "2.6275"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "2.6995"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "2.757"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "2.5376"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "2.3431"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "2.3261"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "2.2036"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "1.9611"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "1.7184"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "1.5965"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "1.4482"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "1.2031"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "1.0698"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "ASI",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - Asia",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          theme: "candy",
          palettecolors: "FB8C00"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "1.9075"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "1.8842"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "2.1082"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "2.4554"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "2.3036"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "1.9889"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "1.9683"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "2.0176"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "1.6823"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "1.3682"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "1.2435"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "1.1661"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "1.0731"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "EUP",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - Europe",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          theme: "candy",
          palettecolors: "FFE0B2"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "1.026"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "1.0652"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "0.9381"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "0.6925"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "0.54"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "0.4218"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "0.354"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "0.2971"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "0.0276"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "-0.1301"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "-0.1558"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "-0.0576"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "-0.0292"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "AFC",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - Africa",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          theme: "candy",
          palettecolors: "E65100"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "2.1242"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "2.338"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "2.5075"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "2.5947"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "2.7175"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "2.8398"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "2.8857"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "2.8243"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "2.6172"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "2.5072"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "2.4853"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "2.5593"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "2.6001"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: "AUS",
      linkedchart: {
        chart: {
          caption: "Average Annual Population Growth - Oceania",
          subcaption: "1955 - 2015",
          yaxisname: "Growth",
          numbersuffix: "%",
          theme: "candy",
          palettecolors: "FB8C00"
        },
        data: [
          {
            label: "1955",
            value: "1.511"
          },
          {
            label: "1960",
            value: "1.6045"
          },
          {
            label: "1965",
            value: "1.5578"
          },
          {
            label: "1970",
            value: "1.455"
          },
          {
            label: "1975",
            value: "1.4727"
          },
          {
            label: "1980",
            value: "1.2404"
          },
          {
            label: "1985",
            value: "1.2398"
          },
          {
            label: "1990",
            value: "1.1853"
          },
          {
            label: "1995",
            value: "1.2006"
          },
          {
            label: "2000",
            value: "1.1244"
          },
          {
            label: "2005",
            value: "1.0724"
          },
          {
            label: "2010",
            value: "1.1255"
          },
          {
            label: "2015",
            value: "1.0397"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFusioncharts
        type="maps/world"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        dataFormat="JSON"
        dataSource={dataSource}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

To know more about drill-down functionality please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/react/add-drill-down-using-react